# why can not download file in wget?

Tags: wget

there is a url:

```
http://118.26.57.16/1Q2W3E4R5T6Y7U8I9O0P1Z2X3C4V5B/218.11.178.160/edge.v.iask.com/95687694.hlv?KID=sina,viask&Expires=1358956800&ssig=WHgIi1wQOW&wsiphost=ipdbm
```

you can download it in chrome or firefox  ,why i cann't  download it  in :

```
wget -c http://118.26.57.16/1Q2W3E4R5T6Y7U8I9O0P1Z2X3C4V5B/218.11.178.160/edge.v.iask.com/95687694.hlv?KID=sina,viask&Expires=1358956800&ssig=WHgIi1wQOW&wsiphost=ipdbm
```

Comment: The url times out for me. Does the problem only occur with this url?

Comment: Try to enclose the url into a single quotes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of the special characters in the URL ('&') you need to put the URL in quotation marks:

```
wget -c "http://118.26.57.16/1Q2W3E4R5T6Y7U8I9O0P1Z2X3C4V5B/218.11.178.160/edge.v.iask.com/95687694.hlv?KID=sina,viask&Expires=1358956800&ssig=WHgIi1wQOW&wsiphost=ipdbm"
```

You could alternatively escape the special characters, but wrapping the URL in quotation marks is probably easiest.